# Free up memory in TDengine database?

Tags: iot, tdengine

the taosd memory increased from 8% to 25% after I executed several queries in taos client, why the memory did't go down after the I get query results? Is there any way to free up  memory in TDengine database?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official document https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/getting-started, you can use "reset query cache" to free up memory.

```
To clean the schema of local cached tables, execute command RESET QUERY CACHE
```